# Odd number ListView

Tags: android, listview, layout, view

I'm trying to make a `ListView` with the situation displayed here: [image]

The ListView items will be loaded from a database so how many items are in it depends on the data returned from the database. But anyways, if it's 1 item or a million, the same pattern should be repeated. 
I'm absolutely clueless how to make a layout like this. Can anyone give an example, a link to another Stack Overflow question (Since I've no clue what this would be called to look it up myself..) similar to this question or a tutorial? I hope someone can help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really I don't understand, What do you want to know? How many elements there are on ListView? HOw to make Loop increment `X` elements?

Comment: this cannot be done with listview..u will have to create a layout dynamically or use some trick...foe odd and even scenarios

Comment: @Aspicas I did an update, hope it makes more sense now ;) It's mainly on how to make a ListView layout like this, not so much about the backend. I know how to make a ListView and populate it, that's not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use the RecycleView.
Adapter have method to set different row view.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // Define a way to determine which layout to use, here it's just evens and odds.
    return position % 2;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2; // Count of different layouts
}
```

if (convertView == null) {
    // You can move this line into your constructor, the inflater service won't change.

```
 mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(getItemViewType(position) == 0)
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_product_complete, null);
    else
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_product_inprocess, null);
    // etc, etc...
```

If you want more information just go through the android recyler View document.

Comment: I was looking for something like that, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042781/android-listview

also you may use table layout with some minor changing.

Answer (score 0):

Read this article [RecyclerView: Grid with header](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html). You can achieve described behavior using `GridLayoutManager` with 2 columns and `GridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup` method.