# Implement multiple layout in list view Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, layout

Hi I am trying to implement mutiple layout in a listview in which filetype is coming from webservices ,Can anyone suggest how to achieve the task Thanks in advance Below is my code i have implemented the below adapter but is giving null in view

Adapter

```
package kbs.com.dynamiclistview;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.RoundedBitmapDisplayer;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by user on 2/13/2016.
*/
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Bean> slist = new ArrayList<Bean>();
    Context context;


    public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<Bean> slist, Context context) {
        this.slist = slist;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return slist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return slist.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final Bean bean = slist.get(i);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (view == null) {
            if (slist.get(i).getFiletype().equalsIgnoreCase("TEXT")) {

                System.out.println("In if text :--" + bean.getFiletype());


                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textlayout, viewGroup, false);

                TextView itemname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemname);

                itemname.setText(bean.filetext);

            }

            if (slist.get(i).getFiletype().equalsIgnoreCase("IMAGES")) {

                //   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imglayout, viewGroup, false);
                System.out.println("In if image :--" + bean.getFiletype());

                ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);


                ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

                imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
                DisplayImageOptions option = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(1000)).cacheInMemory(true)
                        .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.close)
                        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.images).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();


                imageLoader.displayImage(bean.getFileurl(), img, option);


            }

        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: look into this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625326/odd-number-listview/32625449#32625449

Comment: Hi can you help me with some example as i have never worked on recycler view

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView   look this link

Answer (score 0):

You can use getViewTypeCount method under sample :

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

and then we have to implement the logic to select the type of layout to assign to the row according to the position value:

```
@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) 
{
 return (contactList.get(position).getContactType() == ContactType.CONTACT_WITH_IMAGE) ? 0 : 1; 
}
```

You can check type view in getView

```
int type = getItemViewType(position);
```

More info this link [sample](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html)

Comment: Thanks  .. but i want some example